# terraform provider checksum on windows getting failed for grafana

Tags: terraform, grafana

#### Terraform Version

- Terraform: v1.2.6
- Terraform Grafana Provider: "grafana/grafana" 2.3.1

while doing terraform init i am getting following error

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of grafana/grafana...
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing grafana/grafana v2.3.1: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/grafana/grafana: failed to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: the request failed after 2 attempts, please try again later: Get
│ "https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/93446086/5970ea36-ae5e-4b5e-b61a-6099555db0ee?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20230920%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230920T091145Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=ae42ec1d3c6e82af648995086af5736d1fb6ddff54c576ce8a146138067e4d5b&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=93446086&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dterraform-provider-grafana_2.3.1_SHA256SUMS&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream":
│ net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
╵
```

my config

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    grafana = {
      source = "grafana/grafana"
    }
  }
}

provider "grafana" {
  url      = "https://your-grafana-url.com"
  auth = "your-username:password"
}
```

Comment: This would appear to be an issue with the device's network settings.

Comment: This error means that the Terraform Registry successfully told Terraform where to install this provider from -- some GitHub-hosted assets, in this case -- but one of the mentioned URLs was unreachable from your computer. That could either mean that the remote server was subject to an outage at the time you requested it, or it could mean that there's a network configuration problem on your own computer or network that blocks Terraform from connecting to this URL. Unfortunately it's not typically possible to debug this sort of problem in Stack Overflow's Q&A format. 

Comment: thanks, @MatthewSchuchard and Martin, like both said it's a problem with the network. when I changed my network I ran successfully